# нужна помощь с простым скриптом, который поочередно жмет на кнопки с одинаковым классом

Tags: javascript

Имеется такой скрипт, который с определенным интервалом поочередно жмет на кнопки с классом .reply-btn, которые отвечает на уведомления. После нажатия на кнопку к ней добавляется класс и атрибут disabled, но это происходит только если юзер, которому надо ответить находится в сети.
А если юзер не в сети - кнопка после нажатия выдает ошибку от сервера, мол юзер которому вы пытаетесь ответить не в сети, и остается активной. Скрипт начинает бесконечно по ней нажимать, и получает таймаут от сервера за спам.
Вроде как, этот скрипт должен отключать кнопку после нажатия, но по какой то причине этого не происходит.
Не могли бы вы помочь довести до ума этот скрипт, или написать новый, который поочередно будет нажимать все кнопки на странице с классом .reply-btn, после чего добавлять нажатой кнопке атрибут disabled. И если вдруг у кнопки есть этот атрибут - скрипт будет ее игнорировать и идти дальше по списку

```
setInterval(() => {
const button = document.querySelector('.reply-btn:not([disabled])');
if(button){
  button.click();
  button.disabled = true;
} } , 500);
```

сам в программирование ничего не понимаю, по этому, прошу помидорами не бросать :)

Answer (score 0):

Логику скрипта я вижу такой:

1. Получаем все кнопки на странице с помощью метода querySelectorAll и сохраняем их в переменной replyButtons.
2. Запускаем цикл for, который перебирает все кнопки.
3. Внутри цикла проверяем, имеет ли текущая кнопка атрибут disabled с помощью метода hasAttribute. Если да, то при помощи оператора continue пропускаем текущую итерацию и переходим к следующей кнопке.
4. Если кнопка не имеет атрибута disabled, вызываем метод click() для симуляции её нажатия.
5. Для нажатой кнопки добавляем атрибут disabled с помощью метода setAttribute, чтобы заблокировать её повторное нажатие.
   Сам скрипт:

```
const replyButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.reply-btn');

for (let i = 0; i < replyButtons.length; i++) {
  const button = replyButtons[i];
  
  // Проверяем, имеет ли кнопка атрибут "disabled"
  if (button.hasAttribute('disabled')) {
    continue; // Если да, то пропускаем текущую кнопку и переходим к следующей
  }
  
  button.click(); // Нажимаем кнопку
  
  button.setAttribute('disabled', true); // Добавляем атрибут "disabled" к нажатой кнопке
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Вроде как, этот скрипт должен отключать кнопку после нажатия, но по какой то причине этого не происходит.

Твой скрипт вполне себе рабочий... Но вполне может случиться что после клика контент обновляется таким образом что все твои `disabled` будут отсутствовать.

```js
setTimeout(function test(){
  const o = document.querySelector('.reply-btn:not([disabled])')
  if (!o) {
    console.log('Все')
    return
  }
  o.click()
  o.disabled = true
  setTimeout(test, 500)
}, 500)
```

```html
<button class='reply-btn'>Тест 1</button>
<button class='reply-btn'>Тест 2</button>
<button class='reply-btn'>Тест 3</button>
<button class='reply-btn'>Тест 4</button>
<button class='reply-btn'>Тест 5</button>
```

Comment: вполне возможно, об это я даже и не знал. получается, если контент после клика обновляется определенным образом - взаимодействовать с таким элементом с помощью скрипта не получится?

Comment: У вновь появившихся кнопок просто не будет `disabled` и все начнется по новой...